# angular animated notification horizontal stacking

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have been searching all day to no avail to find a way to do this.  Granted I am very VERY new to angular (and coding in general) but every guide I've found doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to make small notification messages show (fixed pos) at the top of the screen sliding in from the right side.  If a second notification comes up before the first has faded (or been closed manually) then it pushes the first notification to the right.  This will show all notification horizontally along the top of the screen.

Am I missing an easy way to do this?  Is there a useful guide out there, or a snippet of something similar?

I don't really have any code to show as I'm having trouble even finding a starting point.

Comment: First step is to get hte notifications apperaing in the right order. Ignore all animations and sliding and interactions. Simply get them stacking vertically as they appear.Then whn you are happy with this, work out how to animate them and get tehm sliding on and off the screen. there is a wealth of ng-animate content around on the net. so you should be able to find the solution. Just don't try to think of it all at once - break it down in to steps and achieve each step to get to the final outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing that you mean:

(**N.B.** *The example below does not use AngularJS at this stage*)

```js
var n = 0;
var notifications = document.getElementsByClassName('notification');
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

function addNotification() {
    if (n > (notifications.length - 1)) return;
    
    notifications[n].style.transform = 'translateX(0)';
    
    for (var i = (n - 1); i > -1; i--) {
        notifications[i].style.transform = 'translateX(' + ((n - i) * (1 + 120 + 1 + 4)) + 'px)';
    }
    
    n++;
}

button.addEventListener('click', addNotification, false);
```

```css
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

.notification {
position: absolute;
top: 6px;
left: 6px;
display: inline-block;
width: 120px;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: rgb(223, 0, 0);
border: 1px solid rgb(191, 0, 0);
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
transform: translateX(200vw);
transition: transform 1s ease-out;
}

button {
margin-top: 36px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="notification">Notification 1</div>
<div class="notification">Notification 2</div>
<div class="notification">Notification 3</div>
<div class="notification">Notification 4</div>

<button type="button">Add Notification</button>
```

Comment: Yes, that is basically what I was looking for.  I just need them on a timer too so they fade after they've been active for a bit.  I'm using notify.js to make the notification.  I just can't get them to stack horizontally like your example.  The default is vertical.

Comment: Are you using `display: inline-block`?